# Who would one hire to make a cabinet door that matches existing cabinets?

Tags: cabinets, custom-cabinetry, hiring

Who would one hire to make a cabinet door that matches existing cabinets?
Is this even plausible, something a carpenter or cabinet maker would entertain?

I bought some nice cabs from a relatively big name brand, but I need doors for a framed-in area and I would like these door to match in style and paint.

Is this possible and if paint matching is a pain, is it reasonable to ask the manufacturer for paint specification (they're big, but contactable and responsive, but sadly do not do custom sized doors)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Carpenters don't usually do custom cabinetry--it requires a special skillset and some specialized tools. Some do, of course, and if you find a high-caliber handyperson he or she could probably get the job done.

A better bet is probably a local custom cabinet shop. They'll have the tooling required to match your design, edge profile, etc., and they'll be more likely to have the products on hand to create the wood finish to match your existing. They're also likely to be more expensive than the handyperson due to overhead costs.

Certainly ask your cabinet seller what they can tell you about finish products. A good cabinet shop won't need it, but it's probably helpful to have anyway. Otherwise just leave one of your doors with the shop while they do your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can usually buy replacement doors either from the manufacturer (if they have direct-to-public sales) or through one of their distributors. The upside is that it will be a perfect match, the downside is the usually high cost. You'll need to know who made the cabinets which isn't always an easy thing to find out. I've replicated doors on several occasions but it's not something most guys want to fool with due to the various bits, tools, and templates you might need. Not so bad for simpler doors, a real bugger on complex ones. Only for no-longer-available designs or where there's no time to source a new one; buy new if you can.

Phil

Phil